# Read from text file as different types- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, int, text-files

I have a text file "input.txt". It looks like this :

```
3


a b c
d e f 
g h i
```

I want to write a python program which reads the 3 as integer and the rest into a list. How can I achieve this? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's your expected output?

Comment: Please refer stackoverflow guidelines on how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How do you want the list to look? `['a b c', 'd e f', 'g h i']`? `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

filename = "input.txt"

with open(filename) as inputFile:
    firstLine = inputFile.readline()
    firstLine = firstLine.strip()
    if not firstLine.isdigit():
        raise TypeError("File content is invalid")

    myInt = int(firstLine)

    myListsVersion1 = list()
    myListsVersion2 = list()
    myListsVersion3 = list()
    for line in inputFile.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) == 0: # or # if not line
            continue

        myListsVersion1.append(line)

        currentLineAsList = line.split()
        myListsVersion2.append(currentLineAsList)
        myListsVersion3.extend(currentLineAsList)

    print(myInt)
    print(myListsVersion1)
    print(myListsVersion2)
    print(myListsVersion3)
```

Based on your input, this will be the result:

```
$ python3 script.py 
3
['a b c', 'd e f', 'g h i']
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

**Suggestion:**

I assume you are new to python? Then you may refer to this cheatsheet below. I guarantee you that with this cheatsheet, you would learn a lot, especially pages 1 to 14:

- https://www.docsity.com/en/python-cheat-sheet-for-beginner/4564823/

For string operations, this is very useful:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods